# how to hide wp-admin from site made with wordpress on live

Tags: wordpress

I am about make my site live, but i don't want some usual suffix in url like **wp-admin**, **wp-login**. Is there any way i can remove it?
And if there is any solution for that, then how would I access my admin panel after that?

Comment: check this out [link](http://wp.trixhub.com/best-plugins-to-hide-wordpress-admin-login/)

Comment: @android93 : Thank you very much. Exactly what i was looking for. But that was premium plugin. I am looking for free.

Comment: if you continue to scroll down on this page you can see the free ones too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Free plugins were recommended to fix this issue;

Lockdown WP Admin: [link](http://wordpress.org/plugins/lockdown-wp-admin/)

Hide Login+ : [link](http://wordpress.org/plugins/hide-login/)

Secure Hidden Login : [link](http://wordpress.org/plugins/secure-hidden-login/)

Comment: Android, link-only answers are not well considered and subject to moderation removal, as links may rot and 404. Can you post **here** a summary of that link? ... ... ... As a matter of fact, your Answer will probably show up in the *Low Quality Posts* review, where people can recommend deletion. See [answer].